# Is there a win32 function to capture contents under the provided layered window?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi

I am developing a screen recording application in C using the win32 API. I have successfully made the capture, and the widget that I have the control buttons such as pause, etc. on. However, I have an issue when trying to capture the screen without/under the layered window. I am using BitBlt on Windows 10, but  moreover the application is supposed to be reliable on Windows 7+. I would like if the panel could somehow be hidden from the capture.

I have tried using SetWindowAffinity, without success. I excepted the layered window to disappear from the capture, however unfortunately that was not the case.

Is there any specific function, or perhaps a parameter, that can resolve the specific issue mentioned?

Comment: There's nothing "underneath" windows, what's normally drawn there isn't drawn when something is shown on top of it. The window which would normally send drawing messages stop sending them. So there is no information for your program to capture.

Comment: Calling `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` is the correct solution here. There's no equivalent on systems prior to Windows 10 2004. @Lundin That mental model breaks down when you consider how desktop composition is implemented. The DWM was introduced in Windows Vista, more than 15 years ago. The [`Windows.Graphics.Capture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture) namespace is testament to the fact that the statement *"there is no information"* is blatantly wrong.